# SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory and defaultRequeueRejected

Tags: spring-amqp

As per doc, defaultRequeueRejected's default value is true, but looking at code it seems its false. I am not sure if I am missing anything or we have to change that in SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.java

EDIT

Sample code, after putting message in test queue, I expect it to stay in queue since its failing but it is throwing it out. I want message to be retried so I configured that in container factory if it fails after retry I want it to be back in queue. I am sure I am missing understanding here.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MsgRequeExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MsgRequeExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "myContainerFactory")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setMissingQueuesFatal(false);

        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(500);
        factory.setAdviceChain(new Advice[] { org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .maxAttempts(2).backOffPolicy(backOffPolicy).build() });
        return factory;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "test", containerFactory = "myContainerFactory")
    public void processAdvisory(Message message) throws MyBusinessException {
        try{
            //Simulating exception while processing message
            String nullString=null;
            nullString.length();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new MyBusinessException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public class MyBusinessException extends Exception {
        public MyBusinessException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am throwing business exception from @RabbitListener and expecting it to reque message but after doing retry at configured times its throwing message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a good description in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Set the default behavior when a message is rejected, for example because the listener
 * threw an exception. When true, messages will be requeued, when false, they will not. For
 * versions of Rabbit that support dead-lettering, the message must not be requeued in order
 * to be sent to the dead letter exchange. Setting to false causes all rejections to not
 * be requeued. When true, the default can be overridden by the listener throwing an
 * {@link AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException}. Default true.
 * @param defaultRequeueRejected true to reject by default.
 */
public void setDefaultRequeueRejected(boolean defaultRequeueRejected) {
    this.defaultRequeueRejected = defaultRequeueRejected;
}
```

Does it make sense to you?

**UPDATE**

To requeue after retry exhausting you need to configure some custom `MessageRecoverer` on the `RetryInterceptorBuilder` with the code like:

```
.recoverer((message, cause) -> {
        ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(cause);
})
```

This way the exception will be thrown to the listener container and according its `defaultRequeueRejected` the message will be requeued or not.

Comment: And as the javadoc says, it is true by default; [see the code here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/1.7.x/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java#L167).

Comment: Thanks , I was looking into actually factory class - SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory. I will create test application and will see why its not requeing message. If its not I will put code here to find my mistake. I use @RabbitListener with containerfactory in annotation and was expecting to reque.

Comment: thank you, actually this issue is only if we use retry interceptor otherwise it reques message fine if it fails in processing.

Comment: I set it to false I see redeliveries and also dead letter queue setup not working